# Pcb etching safety questions (HCl, H2O2, H3PO4)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, safety

I am about to embark on a pcb etching journey, however, I am not sure what safety precautions I should take when handling the products. I know that the reagents should be stored in their original, properly labeled containers, and that normal PPE rules apply. Lab coat, gloves, goggles etc.

What I am unsure about is, is weather or not the stabiliser used in the hydrogen peroxide, phosphoric acid, would be of any concern.

The reaction I am aiming to achieve is the conversion of copper to cupric chloride (Cu(II)Cl2), in a HCl and H2O2 solution. The end product will be stored, as CuCl2 is also a good etchant, and converts into Copper I Chloride when used as such. My main concern is the stabiliser H3PO4 (I assume, bottle just says phosphoric acid,in German phosphorsäure (AB.)) used in the peroxide.

Would this reaction or the following products create phosphorus fumes?
Would the phosphoric acid create gas in product solution as it is stored?
Is there any possibility of the material dissolving or damaging Polypropylene and Latex?
What extra precautions, other than PPE and workplace safety (I. E. Covering the work surface, doing the reaction next to an open window and common sense) do I need to consider?

I appreciate your help, input advice and improvement ideas!
Thank you!

Comment: Phosphoric acid is $\ce{H3PO4}$ and is one of the ingredients in cola soft drinks, among many other things. There will be no “phosphorus fumes”. Ps. Thanks for spelling phosphorus correctly!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll let my autocorrect know, that you appreciate the spelling lol! I know that phosphoric acid is found in soft drinks. However, knowing that certain mixtures can react in an unexpected way, I thought I ask about possibilities. I am mainly thinking about how aqua Regia can dissolve gold, but the components can't.

Comment: Phosphoric acid is $\ce{H3PO4}$ and not $\ce{H3PO3}$ as given in the title of the question. It is a stabilizing agent of $\ce{H2O2}$, but it will not  produce any effect in the reaction of $\ce{HCl + H2O2}$ on copper. It will not react with polypropylene and latex. It will not produce any gas in your mixture. You don't need to consider extra precaution with your experiment. Simply don't put it on your skin or on your clothes. $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{H2O2}$ are corrosive.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't sure, if any further reactions of the products would be harmful. However, now this begs the question of recycling the chemicals....But that's still far off in the future and I will ask again if I don't find anything online. Thank you a lot for your answers!